# Setting a under construction page for IIS6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6

I have an .NET 1.1 web app and I am upgrading to ASP.NET MVC 1.0 app in IIS6.

How do I put up a under construction page so uses see it?

And secondly how can I install the new site and test under
this scenario of having an under construction page??

Malcolm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an [app_offline.htm page](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx).

Comment: users on live shopping site get effected with error when i upload `.DLL` to update code  changes in project, so will [down for maintenance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580911/implement-down-for-maintenance-page) help ? or [statuspage.io](https://www.statuspage.io/) paid service ? [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/238767/asp-net-deployment-maintenance-best-practices) is discussion on similar issue developers face, can you answer ?

Answer (score 1):

@Darin is quite correct but you must make sure it's in the root.  The temptation for MVC applications is to place the html file within the Views folder.  This won't work.