# how to ignore @RenderBody() inside if condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a page where I am validating a condition. if condition true display different page else displays the login page.

```html
@if (sitemaintainmode == "false")
{
    <body>
   
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
          
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
               
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container body-content">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        @Html.Partial("_Footer")

      
        </script>
    </body>
}
else
{
   @RenderPage("~/Views/Account/Error.cshtml"); 
    
}
```

But it gives me an error -

> The "RenderBody" method has not been called for layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml".

Comment: This would be much better handled in the controller than the layout page

Comment: Yeap. In a `MVC` application usually such kind of decisions are taken before you get to the point where the actual view is rendered. I see that you check for maintenance. In this case maybe changing the routing would be a better solution and redirect all request to default action when the site is under maintenance.

Comment: routing from web.config or from controller?

Comment: @Hob check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580911/implement-down-for-maintenance-page I think it's pretty close to what you want to achieve, but in a better way.

Comment: **Don't do this**.  You are adding logic to view.  A view is just to represent data.  Your *logic* in this example should be done in the controller (or ActionFilter) and if it is determined to show the login page, then redirect there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not ignore 
   `RenderBody()` in your code because might be you use this    `Layout="~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"` in your cshtml page.

Create seperate customeErrorPage (View) and Handle your condition in Controller and use   `return RedirectToAction("Login Or Error") or use return View("Login or Errorpage")`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks!! As you suggested I added a condition in controller. it worked.
  public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
           
            var sitemaintainmode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsSiteMaintenanceMode"];
            if(sitemaintainmode == "true")
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Login");
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the action result in the controller, making a redirect to Error view in the Account controller or using customError in the web.config. For instance:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Home/Error_Generic/" >
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Account/Error" />
</customErrors>
```