# How to make website go under maintenance by writing a code in global.asps files using start time and end time key from web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config, global-asax

i'm writing a code for making a site under maintenance.Can anyone help me please.the requirements are as follows.i have a project code i need to make that website go under maintenance **from a specific time to specific time like example from 18 to before 8 it should be under maintenance** and it should be done in **global.asax** file and start and end time should be like keys whose value is present **webconfig** file as shown below can any one please help me out??
code for global.aspx should be like dis...................

```
            // Clear the response stream 
            var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
            httpContext.Response.Clear();
            httpContext.ClearError();
            httpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;


            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
            routeData.Values.Add("action", action);

            // Call error Controller and pass the routeData.
            using (var controller = new ErrorController())
            {
                ((IController)controller).Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext), routeData));
            }
```

the key should be as follows...

```
<add key="StartTime" value="8"/>
    <add key="EndTime" value="18"/>
```

the logic i have taken is as follows

```
public class UnderMaintenanceAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var requestTimestamp = filterContext.HttpContext.Timestamp;
            if (IsUnderMaintenance(requestTimestamp))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    // create your controller/action/view to display your message
                    new RouteValueDictionary
                    {
                    { "controller", "Undermaintenance" },
                    { "action", "Index" }
                    });
            }
        }


        private bool IsUnderMaintenance(DateTime requestTimestamp)
        {
            bool isUnderMaintenance = requestTimestamp.Hour >= 18 || requestTimestamp.Hour < 13;

            return isUnderMaintenance;
        }
    }
```

but i have written that in route config my manager wants me to write it in global.aspx with start key and end key

Comment: can any help please

Comment: just point your DNS to the maintenance page till the time you are done.

Comment: @sheelpriy no actually its a project and i need to be under maintenance every day after eve 6 to mng 8 and again it should get resumed after mng 8 till eve 6

Comment: can any one please help

Comment: Use a global filter and register it conditionally using your constraints from the web.config. I am sure you can make something work from these answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580911/implement-down-for-maintenance-page

Comment: @eaglei22 if i do that then its giving a error too many redirects

Comment: @eaglei22 can u please tell here is the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60070557/localhost-redirected-you-too-many-times-in-mvc

Comment: In your filter put a check to see if you're at the correct action method by seeing what was called, and only redirect if the maintenance action method wasn't requested.

Comment: Also you'll need to register the filter and conditionally check your constraints from the web.config inside the filter to see when to redirect. Since Application_Start() should only run once when the application is first fired up. Rereading my earlier comment I mispoke